# Why is 5.5 returning a different (slgithly result set with these two querieis) the second query is the one that does

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, database-performance

EDIT FINAL: the modified code works on 5.5 however on 5.0 i get a slightly different row set anyone have any ideas...

the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sql_no_cache as job.id,
  job.id as job_id,
  job.job_status,
  job.servee_name,
  kase.plaintiff,
  index_number,
  lawfirm_filenumber,
  DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_received, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_received,
  DATE_FORMAT(job.date_sent_to_court, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_sent_to_court,
  DATE_FORMAT(kase.date_kase_filed, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_kase_filed,
  TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(kase.date_kase_filed) as thedays,
  DATE_FORMAT(kase.court_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') as court_date,
  kase.court_room,
  CONCAT( LUcourt.court_county," - ",LUcourt.court_type) as court_name,
  DATE_FORMAT( job.datetime_served, '%m/%d/%Y') as datetime_served,
  CONCAT( server.namefirst,' ', server.namelast) as server_name

FROM      job 
LEFT JOIN kase        ON job.kase_id = kase.id
LEFT JOIN kasebilling ON kasebilling.kase_id = kase.id
LEFT JOIN server      ON job.server_id = server.id
LEFT JOIN client      ON client.id     = kase.client_id
LEFT JOIN LUcourt     ON LUcourt.id    = kase.court_id

   WHERE job.subscriber_id = 1
ORDER BY job_id + 0
   LIMIT 0,500;

</pre>
i modified the query but it wont run ...

    SELECT DISTINCT sql_no_cache  job.id, job.id as job_id, job.job_status, job.servee_name, kase.plaintiff, index_number, lawfirm_filenumber, DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_received, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_received, DATE_FORMAT(job.date_sent_to_court, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_sent_to_court, DATE_FORMAT(kase.date_kase_filed, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_kase_filed, TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(kase.date_kase_filed) as thedays, DATE_FORMAT(kase.court_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') as court_date, kase.court_room, CONCAT(LUcourt.court_county," - ",LUcourt.court_type) as court_name, DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_served, '%m/%d/%Y') as datetime_served, concat(server.namefirst,' ', server.namelast) as server_name FROM job 
    LEFT JOIN kase ON job.kase_id = kase.id
    LEFT JOIN kasebilling  ON kasebilling.kase_id = kase.id
    LEFT JOIN server ON job.server_id = server.id
    left join client on client.id=kase.client_id
    left join LUcourt on LUcourt.id=kase.court_id  WHERE job.subscriber_id = 1 and job_id in (select distinct job.id from job where job.subscriber_id = '1' order by id+0) LIMIT 0,500
</pre>
```

I have modified the above query as to remove some of the table names ... however what is happened is  if i removed the order by the query goes super quick ...I think its ordering by not just the limit 500 but all the rows... how can i get this working faster with the order by. Any help would be appreciated thanks....

PS: its using a filesort on the order_by...

explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                                                                        | key                                         | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job         | ref    | subscriber_id,subscriber_id-job_loc-client_loc-server_loc,sub_id_idx_servee_name_idx | subscriber_id-job_loc-client_loc-server_loc | 4       | const                 | 362381 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kase        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                              | PRIMARY                                     | 4       | pserve.job.kase_id    |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kasebilling | ref    | kase_id                                                                              | kase_id                                     | 4       | pserve.kase.id        |      2 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | server      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                              | PRIMARY                                     | 4       | pserve.job.server_id  |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                              | PRIMARY                                     | 4       | pserve.kase.client_id |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LUcourt     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                              | PRIMARY                                     | 4       | pserve.kase.court_id  |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

i modified the query but it wont run ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT sql_no_cache  job.id, job.id as job_id, job.job_status, job.servee_name, kase.plaintiff, index_number, lawfirm_filenumber, DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_received, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_received, DATE_FORMAT(job.date_sent_to_court, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_sent_to_court, DATE_FORMAT(kase.date_kase_filed, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_kase_filed, TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(kase.date_kase_filed) as thedays, DATE_FORMAT(kase.court_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') as court_date, kase.court_room, CONCAT(LUcourt.court_county," - ",LUcourt.court_type) as court_name, DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_served, '%m/%d/%Y') as datetime_served, concat(server.namefirst,' ', server.namelast) as server_name FROM job 
LEFT JOIN kase ON job.kase_id = kase.id
LEFT JOIN kasebilling  ON kasebilling.kase_id = kase.id
LEFT JOIN server ON job.server_id = server.id
left join client on client.id=kase.client_id
left join LUcourt on LUcourt.id=kase.court_id  WHERE job.subscriber_id = 1 and job_id in (select distinct job.id from job where job.subscriber_id = '1' order by id+0) LIMIT 0,500
```

Comment: *I think its ordering by not just the limit 500 but all the rows* - How do you want it to order then?

Comment: Adding to what RedFilter said, I will point out that unless you order all the rows, you won't know which rows are the first 500. As for speeding up the query, have you tried indexing `job_id`?

Comment: For the limit to work, mysql has to get ALL of the rows the query would return, order them, **THEN** take the specified first 500 rows.

Comment: so what can i do to make this master... is there anyways i canmake this go faster shouldnt it just beable to take the 300,000 rows from the index do a sort on the index very quickly.... or should i go and buy faster HD's use a different DB engine othan than MyISAM for this application.

Comment: Can we see an `EXPLAIN` and possibly some indexes?

Comment: Is this your original query? There are a few strange column references without a joined table / table alias: `k.kase_id`, `j.server_id`, `server.id`, `job_id`. Is `job_id` referring to a table column or a `SELECT`ed expression (which may be a syntax error)?

Comment: i reposted the orginally query

Comment: BTW, why are you adding 0 to job_id in `ORDER BY job_id + 0`? Can `job_id` be `NULL`? Why aren't you using `job.id` instead of `job_id`? Can they be different?

Comment: to biziclop that was changes i was for obsfucation (craapy job) ...job.id and job_id is the same from the select and addibgng +0 makes it integrate the index as a number

Comment: if its null it wont sort

Answer (score 0):

First ugly try: add the condition `job.subscriber_id = '1'` to `LEFT JOIN job` to reduce the number of total rows to be ORDERed and LIMITed, but also keep it at the WHERE part:

```
FROM      kase
LEFT JOIN job     ON k.kase_id   = kase.id
                 AND job.subscriber_id = '1' /* condition copied here ... */
LEFT JOIN kb      ON kb.kase_id  = kase.id
LEFT JOIN server  ON job.server_id = server.id
LEFT JOIN client  ON client.id   = kase.client_id
LEFT JOIN LUcourt ON LUcourt.id  = kase.court_id
    WHERE job.subscriber_id = '1'            /* ... but also kept here */
 ORDER BY job.id
    LIMIT 0,500;
```

Second try, much uglier: sub-SELECT the first 500 `kase` * `job` combination, and LEFT JOIN the other tables against the subselected rows:

```
FROM
( SELECT * /* you probably have to list & alias column names if necessary */
  FROM      kase
  LEFT JOIN job   ON k.kase_id   = kase.id
      WHERE job.subscriber_id = '1'
   ORDER BY job.id
      LIMIT 0,500
) AS kase_job
/* Now we have 500 rows*/

LEFT JOIN kb      ON kb.kase_id  = kase_job.id
LEFT JOIN server  ON kase_job.server_id = server.id
LEFT JOIN client  ON client.id   = kase_job.client_id
LEFT JOIN LUcourt ON LUcourt.id  = kase_job.court_id

/* If you do `(500 rows) LEFT JOIN whatever` you can be sure you have
   at least 500 rows (never less) here, so you have to ORDER/LIMIT then again
*/

 ORDER BY kase_job.id
    LIMIT 0,500;
```